# How does cal.setTime (new Date()); work?

Tags: java

I want to use the `cal.setTime (new Date());` in my code to update the time, but it dosent work.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Exercise2b {
    public void demo() {
        String message1, message2;
        int hour, minute, second;
        Time dt = new Time();
        hour = dt.getHour();
        minute = dt.getMinute();
        second = dt.getSecond();
        message1 = "The clock is " + minute + " minutes over " + hour + " (+"
                + second + " seconds)";
        message2 = dt.toString();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);
        dt.update();
        message2 = dt.toString();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise2b prog = new Exercise2b();
        prog.demo();
    }
}

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Time {
    private Calendar cal; 
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    public Time() {
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        this.minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        this.second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }
    public int getHour() {
        return this.hour;
    }
    public int getMinute() {
        return this.minute;
    }
    public int getSecond() {
        return this.second;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
    }
    public void update() {
        cal.setTime (new Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work*?

Comment: What time are you trying to set exactly? Is it the time on the Calendar instance or what?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the issue is that you set the `cal` variable but not the `hour`/`minute`/`seconds` variables that are set from the initial value of `cal in the constructor.

This is an example of DRY (don't repeat yourself). In this situation it's easy to get in an inconsistent state. I would simply have your accessor methods query the cal object directly (instead of using the intermediary variables). And perhaps investigate the Joda library for a better / more reliable date/time API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call the update() method you are not refreshing the values of the local variables (second/ minute / hour). Those are already initialized from the constructor.

Comment: @Ayman - if you're going to change the contents of your answer entirely, you should note it (or perhaps provide a new answer) such that comments aren't rendered redundant!

Answer (score 0):

> How does cal.setTime (new Date()); work?

The javadoc states

> Sets this Calendar's time with the given Date.

`new Date()` creates a new `Date` object with the millisecond value of `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

So

```
cal.setTime (new Date());
```

will replace the internal millisecond value of `cal` to that of the new `Date` object.